# Remove underline formating in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

Currently, when I hover over the  links, the text goes white, with no underlining.

However, when the text is **not** being hovered over, it is purple and underlined; how can I remove this decoration, so that the text is white and not underlined?

[image]

and here is the code

```
.sidebar
{

    padding-left:770px;
    margin-bottom:-400px;
    width:100px;
    text-decoration:none;

}
.sidebar ul
{
    padding-left:0px;

    color:Blue;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Candara;
        width: 250px;
        background-color:#2A5395;
        color:White;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left:10px;
 text-decoration:none;
}
.sidebar li
{
padding-top:10px;
border-color:#ECECEC !important;
color:White;
text-decoration:none;
}

.sidebar a:hover {

    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:White;

}
```

markup

```
<div class="sidebar">
<h2 class="indxparaz">HOT LINKS</h2>
<ul class="sidebar">
<li><a href="Upcoming_events.htm">Up Coming Events</a> </li>
<li><a href="Member_ship.html">Membership</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.sidebar a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:White;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here You Add Some CSS Code into your CSS file like

```css
.sidebar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidebar a,
.sidebar a:hover,
.sidebar a:active {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
.sidebar a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}
```

also if you do not want text-decoration anywhere for sidebar link, go for 
    .sidebar a{ 
        text-decoration :none !important;
    }

Answer (score 0):

`.sidebar a{text-decoration: none;color:white;}`